# Ubuntu Software Center won't download any program! What can I do?

Tags: software-installation, software-center

I've tried everything I could find on the Internet, but still can't download anything from the Ubuntu Software Center.

It won't install anything and it won't do any progress when downloading. I have even tried reinstalling Ubuntu.

When I try to download anything, it says "updating cache".

By the way, I'm using 13.04, and it says I have Internet, but the Internet won't work, I also used the b34 or 43 method.

Here is the outcome when I typed `software-center` in the terminal: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6791762/

```
2014-01-21 15:11:07,927 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2014-01-21 15:11:10,001 - softwarecenter.region - WARNING - failed to use geoclue: 'org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Error.notAvailable: Geoclue master client has no usable Address providers'
2014-01-21 15:11:10,316 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2014-01-21 15:11:10,348 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2014-01-21 15:11:10,367 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py', 51, 'find_module')'
2014-01-21 15:11:10,367 - root - ERROR - Could not find any typelib for LaunchpadIntegration
2014-01-21 15:11:10,449 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2014-01-21 15:11:10,646 - softwarecenter.backend.spawn_helper - WARNING - exit code 1 from helper for '['/usr/share/software-center/piston_generic_helper.py', '--datadir', '/usr/share/software-center/', 'RatingsAndReviewsAPI', 'review_stats']'
2014-01-21 15:11:10,646 - softwarecenter.backend.spawn_helper - WARNING - got error from helper: 'WARNING:__main__:connecting to http://reviews.ubuntu.com/reviews/api/1.0/review-stats/any/any/: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Run `software-center` from a terminal and add the output here. This is still however likely a bug.

Comment: Heres an image for how it looks like, since the output was too long: http://www.mediafire.com/view/myfiles/#omyiwasbbtm5no2

Comment: Actually we prefer the output here even if it's long.

Comment: But it's too long to put it here.

Comment: @user235747 Please use a text paste site such as http://paste.ubuntu.com. Then provide the URL here, preferably by editing your question. (This will make it easier for people to immediately figure out what the issue is in your question, automatically get your question reviewed for opening, and draw attention to your question which could lead to someone seeing it who knows the answer.) Thanks!

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6791762/ that's the paste ubuntu link!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to install `SubDownloader` an app to download/upload movie subtitles.
Open up your software center and open the subdownloader page. You can search for it then click more details. Check image below:

[image]

Don't click the install button but scroll down till you see the version name and number. It's usually between 'People also installed' and 'reviews' sections. Copy the name of the app without the version number - in this case, copy just `subdownloader`.

Go to your terminal and type `sudo apt-get install subdownloader` Though now you'll replace the word 'subdownloader' with the one you copied earlier and press enter.

In case of any error messages, paste them and provide us the link.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6949150/

Comment: Which package are you trying to install?

Comment: I'm trying to install MonoDevelop

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` then `sudo apt-get install monodevelop` In case of any errors, edit your question and include them.