# How to install Synaptics touchpad manager with terminal?

Tags: drivers, command-line, software-center

I need to get this to get my touch-pad working but I am unable to install it with `Ubuntu Software Center` as it says `

```
"Update Error: Require Installation Of Untrusted Packages"
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install kde-config-touchpad`

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/420394/163331) on how to download apps via the terminal by copying their names.